# React Native version mismatch. JavaScript version: 0.63.4 Native version: 0.71.1

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal

React Native version mismatch.
JavaScript version: 0.63.4
Native version: 0.71.1

after upgrading the application, running smoothly but getting this error that moves the RN-app to dead zone.
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.1",